# Convert the datetime value to floor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When go through our application's existing stored procedure, I saw below code:

```
cast(floor(cast(@weekdate as float)) as datetime)
```

Any one explain purpose behind this code? `@Weekdate` is a `datetime` field.

Comment: The purpose is to remove the time component.  The preferred method is now `cast(@weekdate as date)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It truncates the time from the datetime.

```
SELECT DateAndTime = GETDATE(),
       DateOnly = cast(floor(cast(GETDATE() as float)) as datetime)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/3783/0)</kbd>

Here is another way that i use on SQL-Server 2005:

```
dateadd(dd, datediff(dd,0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

SQL-Server 2008 introduced the [`date` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx), then it's easier:

```
cast(@weekdate as date)
```